# windows header control and MSAA

Tags: listview, winapi, windows-10, accessibility, atl

I am trying to operate the common header control (click on a column) via IAccessible. I have this simple piece of code that works up to windows XP and win7, but for windows 10 it does nothing

```
CComPtr<IAccessible> iacc;
hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hw, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&iacc));
CComVariant col(1); // try to click first column
#ifdef _DEBUG
LPDISPATCH pp = 0;
hr = iacc->get_accChild(col, &pp);
ATLASSERT(!pp); // no "real" child objects
CComBSTR bs;
hr = iacc->get_accDefaultAction(col, &bs); // returns CLICK
#endif
hr = iacc->accDoDefaultAction(col);
ATLASSERT(S_OK==hr);
// call succeeds but no HDN_ITEMCLICK sent!?
```

pretty straightforward, given the header window handle obtain the accessibility interface then try to click on a column (child item) by number. accDoDefaultAction returns S_OK but the listview control doesn't receive HDN_ITEMCLICK

I suppose the port to windows 10 at some stage introduced a bug in the header control MSAA code

Comment: Seems unlikely that it's a Windows bug.....

Comment: and how did you come up with your verdict?

Comment: Experience suggests that the error is more likely to be on your side. That's where I would concentrate my efforts if I were you.

Comment: well here's the code, try it for yourself and see whose bug is it

Comment: Clearly there's nothing we can do for you. Since you are certain it's a Windows defect, you can only submit a bug report and move on.

Comment: I can confirm that Windows 7 sends LVN_COLUMNCLICK and HDN_ITEMCLICK and Windows 8 does not!

Answer (score 0):

The [Invoke control pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671279(v=vs.85).aspx) in UI Automation seems to work correctly. Not sure if this is by design or a bug in the MSAA/UIA bridge. If you support a wide range of targets your only option is to try both methods.